# The has-a relationship and the proper practice

Tags: java, relationship, composition, aggregation

Recently I am doing a coding exercises I need to make my project , and so far I am practicing it with the code below what I want to ask is that, is this a has a relationship? am I doing the right practice? look at my code, sorry for my bad english

```
public class Personal {

        private String firstName;
        private String middleInitial;
        private String lastName;
        private int age;

        public Personal(String firstName,String middleInitial , String lastName , int age){
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setMiddleInitial(middleInitial);
            setLastName(lastName);
            setAge(age);
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName){
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getFirstName(){
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setMiddleInitial(String middleInitial){
            this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
        }

        public String getMiddleInitial(){
            return middleInitial;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName){
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getLastName(){
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setAge(int age){
            this.age = age;
        }

        public int getAge(){
            return age;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return String.format("First Name: "+getFirstName()+"\nMiddle Initial: "+getMiddleInitial()+
                                    "\nLast Name: "+getLastName()+"\nAge: "+getAge());
        }
}
```

Contact Class

```
public class Contact {
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private String contactNumber;

    public Contact(String address,String contactNumber, String email){
        setAddress(address);
        setContactNumber(contactNumber);
        setEmail(email);
    }

    public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber){
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }

    public String getContactNumber(){
        return contactNumber;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("Address: "+getAddress()+"\nContact Number: "+getContactNumber()+
                                "\nEmail Address: "+getEmail());
    }
}
```

Employee Class

```
public class Employee {
    private Personal personal;
    private Contact contact;

    public Employee(Personal personal, Contact contact){
        this.personal = personal;
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
        this.personal.setFirstName(firstName);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.format(personal.toString()+contact.toString());
    }
}
```

And the Test class

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Personal personalHerp = new Personal("John","M","Doe",18);
        Contact contactHerp = new Contact("88 Herp Derp St U mad New york","724-15-70","fido.com");
        Employee employeeHerp = new Employee(personalHerp,contactHerp);
        System.out.println(employeeHerp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you say something about the model you're trying to create and which relations you want to model? There are some associations in there, but without information on what you're trying to accomplish it's hard to answer your question.

Comment: why String.format in toString() methods? Just delete invocation of this method. String.format is useful for String.format("Hello %s!","world") which gives one string "Hello world!". In your case - it is not needed. Just write "return personal.toString() + contact.toString()".

Comment: ivan sopov, what will I use ? then?  I want to return all of the attributes in text in my personal and contact class

Comment: dudes, all he/she asked was whether it is a has-a relationship (and it is).  why bug him/her (and therefore confuse him/her) about all the rest of the stuff.  let him/her learn at his pace and get to the string stuff later once he/she understands the "has-a".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since `Employee` doesn't extend `Personal` it *has* a `Personal` and a `Contact`.

I guess you'd rather like `Employee` to *be* a `Personal` and thus it should look like this:

```
public class Employee extends Personal {
  private Contact contact;
  ...
}
```

So to summarize:

- *is-a* means a class/object extends another class or implements an interface, i.e. A is-a B if `A extends B` or `A implements B`
- *has-a* means that a class/object has a variable of that type, like `Contact contact` in your `Employee` class, which means `Employee` has-a contact.

Comment: but I already did that with my past class modeling, but in the end I  ended up having 12 constructors, sorry for the typo name but it's actually PersonalInformation, anyways anymore suggestion?

Comment: Think a bit before creating the class structure and decide what is closely related to `Personal`-s and what is not. Closely related things should go to a superclass, the rest what can be attributes of other entities (such as contact info, or location,, or whatever) should go to separate classes.

Comment: I see, but if I do that I'll have 5 parameters in my constructor , isn't that bad?

Comment: @KyelJmD That depends on what those parameters are, but 5 parameters aren't that bad. You might, however, create a container object like your `PersonalInformation` (in which case `Personal` might _have_ a `PersonalInformation` attribute).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a "has-a" relationship (exactly as we discussed in your other question).